# Get data of objects array dynamically by variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet

I use [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) for my map.

I added the following markers:

```
var markers = [];
var markerOne = L.circleMarker([000000,000000],{icon: MyIcon, alt:"M1"}).addTo(map);
    markers.push(markerOne);
var markerTwo = L.circleMarker([000000,000000],{icon: MyIcon, alt:"M2"}).addTo(map);
    markers.push(markerTwo);
var markerThree = L.circleMarker([000000,000000],{icon: MyIcon, alt:"M3"}).addTo(map);
    markers.push(markerThree);
var markerFour = L.circleMarker([000000,000000],{icon: MyIcon, alt:"M4"}).addTo(map);
    markers.push(markerFour);
// aso.
```

All works fine. **Now I want to group up some of this markers dynamically**:

1 - The "static" way works:

```
 var markerGroup1 = [markerOne, markerThree];
 var MyMarkerGroup = L.layerGroup(markerGroup1); // set of markers
```

2 - But all my attempts to do it dynamically fail:

```
 var markerGroup1 = "markerOne, markerThree"; // As info: I got this names dynamically by a function
 markerGroup1 = MyMarkers.split(","); // To get them as array
 var MyMarkerGroup = L.layerGroup(markerGroup1); // set of markers
```

In the dev. console I see that in the second example the "objects data of the markers name" will not be catched. Why?

[image]

Comment: @mplungjan How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

That is because
`L.layerGroup([markerOne, markerThree])` is an array of markers and
`L.layerGroup(["markerOne", "markerThree"])`is an array of strings

This will work

```
var markers = {
  "markerOne": L.circleMarker([000000,000000],{icon: MyIcon, alt:"M1"}).addTo(map),
  "markerTwo": L.circleMarker([000000,000000],{icon: MyIcon, alt:"M2"}).addTo(map),
  "markerThree": L.circleMarker([000000,000000],{icon: MyIcon, alt:"M3"}).addTo(map),
  "markerFour": L.circleMarker([000000,000000],{icon: MyIcon, alt:"M4"}).addTo(map)
};


var group1 = "markerOne, markerThree".split(", ");  // add the space or have no spaces!
var markerGroup1= group1.map(markerName => markers[markerName])
var MyMarkerGroup = L.layerGroup(markerGroup1); // set of markers
```

Comment: Thx for your example. My problem is, that I need the "name of markers" to group them up. So "group1 = "0,2".split(",");" will not work for me.

Comment: Sorry for that, but if I am right, this will also not work. I get the name of a marker by my script, for example "markerOne". Now I have to add this marker name dynamically to the LayerGroup. I dont know the exact position of it inside the array, I just know the variable name (markerName).

Comment: Big thx for your updated version. Give me some min pls, I will try it.

Comment: I am sorry again, I have the problem that I exactly need the structure from above, like the "var markerOne = L.circleMarker ..." push way. Otherwise the rest of my scripts will not work. Also leaflet seems to have a problem with this way of "object declaring".

Comment: I am wondering myself, why is it not possible to just add this marker names dynamically inside the "[]"? So that I get [markerOne, markerThree] and not ["markerOne", "markerThree"]?

Comment: Because you have strings. You would need to do an eval (not recommended) to do this